# Javascript undefined data: can't post form data into db

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

I'm building a HTML form that can connect to a php api in order to get client data and then PUT it into mysql database so that Ican update user stats.

Right now I'm converting data into a JSON object and then I'm using JSON.stringify to create a string in order to send that string value into HTTP request.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // (*1*) show (filled out) html form when the user clicks on the 'update product' button
  $(document).on('click', '.aggiorna_persona_button', function(e) { // first par = event; second (optional) par = selector (in this case the class); last par = event handler
    e.preventDefault();

    // get product id
    const giorni = $(this).attr('data-id'); // this = clicked button; read the value of data-id attribute

    sendRequest("leggi_uno.php?giorno=" + giorni, data => {
      let
        aggiorna_persona_html = indietro_button();
      aggiorna_persona_html += `
                    <!-- build 'update product' html form -->
                    <form id='aggiorna_persona_form'name="aggiorna_persona_form" action='#' method='post' border='0'>
                        <table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>
                            
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>Altezza</td>
                                <td><input value=\"` + data.height_utente + `\" type='number' name='height_utente' step="0.1" min="0.5" max="2.2" lang="en" id="altezza" class='form-control' required /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Peso utente</td>
                                <td><input value=\"` + data.weight_utente + `\" type='number' name='weight_utente' step="0.1" min="0" max="200.0" lang="en" id="peso" class='form-control' required /></td></td>
                            </tr>
    
                            <tr>
                                <!-- hidden 'product id' to identify which record to update -->
                                <td><input value=\"` + data.giorno + `\" name='giorno' id="giornata" type='hidden' /></td>
                                <!-- button to submit form -->
                                <td>
                                    <button type='submit'  class='btn btn-info'>
                                        <span class='fa fa-edit'></span> Aggiorna fumetto
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>`;

      // inject to 'page-content' of our app
      $("#contenuti_pagina").html(aggiorna_persona_html);

      // chage page title
      cambiaTitolo("Aggiorna persona");
    });
  });

  // (*2*) send updated product data to the update service when the user submit the form
  $(document).on('submit', '#aggiorna_persona_form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // get form data
    const form_data = JSON.stringify($(this).serializeObject());
    console.log(form_data);

    sendRequest("aggiorna.php", mostraPersone, "PUT", form_data);
  });
});
```

Here is the function used to transform DOM object form into javascript oject and then JSON:*

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
  let o = {};
  let a = this.serializeArray();
  $.each(a, function() {
    if (o[this.age_utente] !== undefined) {
      if (!o[this.age_utente].push) {
        o[this.age_utente] = [o[this.age_utente]];
      }
      o[this.age_utente].push(this.value || '');
    } else {
      o[this.age_utente] = this.value || '';
    }
  });
  return o;
};
```

Edge console shows an undefined array:

> eg.   {"undefined":["25","12"]}

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The array returned by `serializeArray()` contains object in the form `{name: "field_name", value: field_value}`. So there's no `this.age_utente`, just `this.name` and `this.value`.

```js
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
  let o = {};
  let a = this.serializeArray();
  $.each(a, function() {
    if (!o[this.name]) {
      o[this.name] = [];
    }
    o[this.name].push(this.value)
  });
  return o;
}
```